# Why does object '..JSON' not found error occur using tidyjson package, bind_rows, and mutate together in R?

Tags: json, r, dplyr

Does anyone know why an error occurs using the tidyjson package, bind_rows(), and mutate() together in the following example?

```
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)

# Define a simple JSON array
people <- '
[
    {
    "name": "bob",
    "age": 32
    }, 
    {
    "name": "susan", 
    "age": 54
    }
]'

# Structure the data
people_df <- people %>%
    gather_array %>%
    spread_values(
        name = jstring("name"),
        age = jnumber("age"))
```

Using `bind_rows()` and `mutate()` together seems to cause an error:

```
people_df2 <- people_df %>%
    bind_rows(people_df) %>%
    mutate(city = "toronto")
```

Output:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '..JSON' not found
```

However, using only `bind_rows()` or `mutate()` or adding in `as_data_frame()` work:

```
people_df2 <- people_df %>%
    bind_rows(people_df)

people_df2 <- people_df %>%
    mutate(city = "toronto")

people_df2 <- people_df %>%
    as_data_frame() %>%
    bind_rows(people_df) %>%
    mutate(city = "toronto")
```

Comment: Look at `attributes(people_df)` and `attributes(people_df %>% bind_rows(people_df))`. Original one is a class `tbl_json` with JSON attribute. That is not there after `bind_rows()`. Doing `as_data_frame()` before `bind_rows()` works because it converts to data frame first.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, converting to `data_frame` using `as_data_frame()` is a way around the problem:

```
people_df2 <- people_df %>%
    as_data_frame() %>%
    bind_rows(people_df) %>%
    mutate(city = "toronto")
```

Just seems like this should not be needed

Comment: If you prefer less typing, `tbl_df()` is another way to toss out the JSON component once parsing is finished.  For what it's worth, it looks like `bind_rows` is intended for support in the `tidyjson` package.  See issue [here](https://github.com/jeremystan/tidyjson/issues/58)

Comment: Thanks, @C.Arendt